# Nasty way to go

Tags: phrases

I watched a film with Simon Pegg yesterday. The film is "Hot Fuzz". It is a very funny film I recommend you to watch.

There is a phrase which is repeated for several times during the film.

> **Nasty way to go**

Could anyone please tell me what that means? I google it, but no result found. Thanks in advance.

Cheers from Kazakhstan!!!

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. For the benefit of many of us who have not seen the film, you might offer the context in which this remark was used: a line or two before, or set the scene for us. Otherwise it is very hard to know what specifically the remark means in the film.

Comment: Having just read a brief plot outline, it seems very probable that _a nasty way to go_ means _a nasty way to die_.

Comment: @Shoe most certainly. I wonder if this question is a better fit on ELL? [Go/gone as a euphemism for death](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go) is pretty easy to find.

Comment: I'd bet a question like this one would have been more welcomed on the site for [ell.SE]. You should check it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I do confirm.
In this case it means> a bad way to die.

Comment: I think you're right, but it is customary here to provide some documentation for such answers: a dictionary definition or citations in which the meaning is defined by the context.